# Windows 7 error: Windows cannot access \\servername; The network path was not found

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, network-shares

There are five servers we connect to here at work.  All of a sudden, I have been unable to access three of them through Windows Explorer using the UNC path.  However, I can remote into them with Remote Desktop just fine.  I had a co-worker try to access the share via Explorer and it works just fine for him.

This started happening to me as soon as I remoted into one of the servers and changed my user password.  The only thing I can think of is that my login credentials are still stored somewhere.  I've tried rebooting and logging out of Windows, but it still refuses to let me in.

Connectivity is obviously not an issue since I can remote into these servers.  Anyone have a clue what I can do?

Comment: Did you tried using \\"IP address" ???? Maybe your Windows name resolution server is having problems.

Comment: I was able to get to it through the IP just fine.  Any idea what I can do to fix this?  If you do, you might want to post it as an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: Are you on a Windows domain?  The same one as the servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try an `IPConfig /flushdns`.

You can also use NSLookup to try and determine what's answering your DNS request, and if it gives a proper response.

Comment: Just noting that `nslookup` will likely give different results -- typically Windows attempts NBNS and/or LLMNR before DNS.